# Loop through a table to fetch all records with a particular ID and delete the corresponding files in a folder only deleting one file in folder in php

Tags: php

I tried to query a table to get all records with a particular ID so as to delete the records from the table as well as unlink the corresponding files from a folder on the server but only the first file is getting deleted while all records are getting deleted as it should be.

Below is my code

```
$querydpp = "SELECT dpID, dpphoto, fprid FROM projectdrawingplanstbl WHERE fprid=?";
$stmtdpp = $connREMAX->prepare($querydpp);
$stmtdpp->bind_param('i', $fpid);
$stmtdpp->execute();
$stmtdpp->store_result();
$totalRowsdpp = $stmtdpp->num_rows;
$stmtdpp->bind_result($dpID, $dpphoto, $fprid);
```

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRowsdpp; $i++) {
            
    $queryd = "SELECT dpphoto FROM projectdrawingplanstbl WHERE fprid=?";
    $stmtd = $connREMAX->prepare($queryd);
    $stmtd->bind_param('i', $fpid);
    $stmtd->execute();
    $stmtd->store_result();
    $stmtd->bind_result($dpphotod);
    $stmtd->fetch();

    if($dpphotod!="")
    {
        unlink($targetd . $dpphotod);
        unlink($thumbtargetd . $dpphotod);
    }           
        
    $stmtpd = $connREMAX->prepare("DELETE FROM projectdrawingplanstbl WHERE fprid=?");
    $stmtpd->bind_param('i', $fpid);
    $results_delpd = $stmtpd->execute();
    $stmtpd->close();
            
}
```

I was expecting all corresponding files with the ID in the table to be deleted from the folder, but its not. Only one file at a time is getting deleted.

***My appologies*** the first query is what I used to have the files displayed on the page so the person deleting can see what files they are deleting. While the 2nd query in the loop was what I used to get the records to delete.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem or a MySQL problem? Dumping `$dpphotod` or the variables used to delete the file could already help

Comment: What is the purpose of that `$queryd = ...` query? You have already selected the `dpphoto` from that very same table in your first query, the `$totalRowsdpp` you are looping over there _already_ contain that value.

Comment: We don't know, if your `fprid` is unique or not. If it was, then the first query could only ever return a maximum of one record - so no real reason to _loop_ over the result then. And if it wasn't - then your inner query _selects_ all of the records corresponding to that ID, but you are fetching & processing only the first one of those. You delete that _one_ file, but then you delete _all_ records with that ID. So even if the loop tries to make the query with that same ID again on the next iteration, it won't find any records any more.

Comment: @NicoHaase its a php problem. If i used a checkbox to identify the files to delete and used `$chkbxk = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];` within the loop, it works. but I don't want to select individual files. I want to delete all in one go

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. If this is not a MySQL problem, please remove that tag

Comment: @CBroe the fprid is a relational table ID not the main ID of the table. Multiple records in the table contain the same fprid

Comment: @CBroe ***but you are fetching & processing only the first one of those. You delete that one file, but then you delete all records with that ID. So even if the loop tries to make the query with that same ID again on the next iteration, it won't find any records any more.*** This is exactly what i can figure out is going on but how do i resolve this?

Comment: @CreanixDeveloper see the answer I've written below

Comment: `the first query is what I used to have the files displayed on the page so the person deleting can see what files they are deleting. While the 2nd query in the loop was what I used to get the records to delete`...but these are the exact same records, so you don't need to select them again. The two queries are identical (aside from the selection of one extra column in the first one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are wrong:

1. Your second `SELECT` query is redundant, because your first `SELECT` already selected all the necessary rows and columns.
2. Your second `SELECT` is causing a problem, because instead of fetching a new row every time you loop, you would keep fetching the same (first) row again from the query, because you're re-executing that query every time.
3. However that problem never actually happens because within the loop you also `DELETE` all the records, so the second time the loop runs there is nothing to select anymore.

In other words, the logic needs a bit of a rethink.

Here's a possible approach:

1. Query the records once and loop through them
2. Don't delete anything from the database until all the selected rows have been processed and the files deleted

```
$querydpp = "SELECT dpID, dpphoto, fprid FROM projectdrawingplanstbl WHERE fprid=?";
$stmtdpp = $connREMAX->prepare($querydpp);
$stmtdpp->bind_param('i', $fpid);
$stmtdpp->execute();
$result = $stmtdpp->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $dpphoto = $row["dpphoto"];

    if($dpphoto != "")
    {
        unlink($targetd . $dpphoto);
        unlink($thumbtargetd . $dpphoto);
    }           
}

$stmtpd = $connREMAX->prepare("DELETE FROM projectdrawingplanstbl WHERE fprid=?");
$stmtpd->bind_param('i', $fpid);
$results_delpd = $stmtpd->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the logic rethink.  A few things I have noticed with the approach you have given, 1, the get_results() and using a while loop rather than the for loop I was trying to use

Comment: I will try this approach now

Comment: @CreanixDeveloper the behaviour of both types of loop would be the same if  you write them correctly, so you can choose which way to do it. That's just how I normally write things like this. The important point is that you don't  need to have two SELECT queries doing the same thing

Comment: @CreanixDeveloper, please mark this answer as accepted if you find it correct (and upvote it if you find it helpful)